# Javascript: alert checking for mouseover and mouseout firing multiple times

Tags: javascript

Writing a code that does the following:

1. Adds a mouse listener to a web-page on load
2. Checks what element the mouse is positioned over
3. If the mouse is positioned over an anchor tag then execute a certain functionality if it stays there for a certain period of time before leaving. For now am just arbitrarily using 10000 ms

Below is a sample code that I'm using as a testbed

```
<html>
<head></head>
<title>A test page</title>
<body>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
    document.addEventListener("mouseover", checkElement, false);

    function checkElement(ev){
         var elm = ev.target || ev.srcElement;
            if(elm.tagName === 'A'){
            var focusTime = new Date().getTime();
            elm.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {tellTime(focusTime)}, false);
         }
    }

    function tellTime(focusTime){
        var blurTime = new Date().getTime();
        if ((blurTime - focusTime) > 10000) {
            alert ('You spent a long time there');
        }
    }
    </script>

    <a href="www.google.co.in">This is a hyperlink</a>
    <p> This is just some bloody text </p>
</body>

</html>
```

When testing what I have found is that when the alert is fired it gets fired multiple times; twice, thrice or even more. I wanted to know why this could be happening and what I can do to avoid firing the alert multiple times for the same element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repeated event bindings... Try the following code out.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<title>A test page</title>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    document.addEventListener("mouseover", checkElement, false);

    function checkElement(ev){
        var elm = ev.target || ev.srcElement;
        if(elm.tagName === 'A'){
            var focusTime = new Date().getTime();
            elm.addEventListener("mouseout", tellTime, false);
        }
        function tellTime(){
            elm.removeEventListener("mouseout", tellTime, false);
            var blurTime = new Date().getTime();
            if ((blurTime - focusTime) > 2000) {
                alert ('You spent a long time there');
            }
        }
}


</script>
<body>
    <a href="www.google.co.in">This is a hyperlink</a>
    <p> This is just some bloody text </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are adding multiple `mouseout` events to the element.

You will need to unbind the previous one, or allocate it normally and let `focusTime` be scoped to both functions.

Comment: Does allocate it normally mean without unbinding the previous event?